# MVC long running EF stored procedure call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was wondering what would be a simple and effective way to trigger a long lasting/running stored procedure call via the ASP.NET MVC 3 User Interface having the web UI to return immediately and the user "allowed" to close the browser and check again later.

I really would not like to create a windows service only for this, I was thinking about using the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` approach, a recycle would not even be a big problem and application is not going to be under heavy load, is an internal WebUI we are making to simplify some maintenance tasks.

Has anybody tried the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` approach and used application cache or similar way to persist the status of the stored procedure call like "EXECUTING" or "COMPLETED" ?

Comment: you can use ansyncController and UI can return almost immediately. On callback you can store a notification for specific user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that gets queued into the ThreadPool steals resources to ASP.NET request processing queues. If you plan to run many long-running tasks, then you should use a different thread/thread pool. If it's just once in a while, then it's surely a viable solution.

In any case, keep in mind that you cannot access application cache/session from outside a web request, so you must find another way to hold the status of the task.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into hosting a [WCF service through MSMQ http binding.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395217.aspx)  This way, you could insert this web service request into an asynchronous queue directly through an http call.

To make the service easier to consume from the UI, you could make the [WCF endpoint a REST endpoint.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd547388)

You would be able to post directly to your REST service from javascript, leveraging out of the box queuing technology provided by Microsoft, and not have to deal with multi-threading.

You could also use the [AsyncController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx), and out of the box solution provided by Microsoft.